# Visual Studio Code First C++ Project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I'm investigating using **VS Code** for our current **C++** project on **Linux** (using **gcc** to compile). Though I'm familiar with Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code is a different beast. I'm just trying to get a sample C++ app up in it, but even following [this simple tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/) has proved fruitless.

It all falls apart [early on](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/#Taskforbuilding). I have a one file program open. When I bring up the command palette, I don't have the "**Tasks: Configure Task Runner**" task. Since all the following steps depend on this one, I don't know how to proceed.

Was that command removed? Is there a better/more current step-by-step guide? I've heard great things about VS Code and really want to get it working.

Comment: You have to configure the path for the compiler

Comment: The official docs have step-by-step instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp And if you really don't have that option in the command palette you can just manually create the "tasks.json" file

Comment: I found the official doc, but was reluctant to follow it since it says "Preview" in the title. Followed it; it worked. Thanks!